# C# System.Timers.Timer array countdown

Tags: c#, arrays, timer, integer, system.timers.timer

```
static void Main()
{
    int timersLength = 4;
    int interval = 1000;
    int[] timerNum = new int[timersLength];
    Timer[] timers = new Timer[timersLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < timersLength; i++)
    {
        timerNum[i] = i;
        timers[i] = new Timer(interval);
        //Console.WriteLine($"Timer {timerNum[i]} is running");
        timers[i].Elapsed += (o, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Timer {timerNum[i]} is running");
        };
    }

    foreach (Timer timer in timers)
        timer.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

whenever I'm trying to make a countdown to the Timer array it gives an

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array."

on the Elapsed line:

```
timers[i].Elapsed += (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Timer {timerNum[i]} is running");
};
```

The code seems fine but for some reason it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a class to store the name of the Timer next to it then you can simply create a `Dictionary<Timer, string>` collection for mapping.

```
Dictionary<Timer, string> timers = new Dictionary<Timer, string>(timersLength);

for (int i = 0; i < timersLength; i++)
{
    var timer = new Timer(interval);
    timers[timer] = $"Timer {i}";
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, _) => Console.WriteLine($"{timers[(Timer)sender]} is running");
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<Timer, string> mapping in timers)
    mapping.Key.Start();
```

- The `Elapsed` event handler will be called by passing the `sender` object
- The `sender`'s type is `object` so you need to cast it to `Timer`
- That object can be used to do the look up in the `timers` collection
- Since yo don't use the `EventArgs` of the `Elapsed` I suggest to use the [discard operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards) there to express your intent more clearly

Comment: Very appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: @PinkiePie Thanks, if you have found it useful please consider to upvote it. If you think that the proposed solution solves your problem then please consider to mark it as the answer. Have a nice day!